# "add a user" doesn't work for Chat explicit read or write access

Tags: support, chat

I tried adding [Sandeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839946/sandeep) by granting him write access to my [public chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/1204/vonc), by clicking add a user ion the "Explicit write access" line, entering:

- Sandeep id (839946)
- Sandeep profile address on SO or on chat.SO
- Sandeep name (and carefully selecting the right gravatar, since they are so many of Sandeep out there ;) )

Nothing worked: the list of user with "Explicit write access" remains desperately empty (operations done with a FireFox 5 on a Windows Xp).
Even when Sandeep gained more than 20 rep, I still couldn't grant him any right, and <del>he still reported seeing the room as read-only</del> (after log out/log in in the room, with more than 20 rep, he is now able to participate in it).

Is there anything I missed (some sort of "validation" button)?
Or does Sandeep have to log out from SO and log back in?

Comment: Note: yes, I know, the "get a room feature" kicked in and Sandeep is able to chat in that special room for one particular question. But this bug report is more general and is **about the absence of any GUI response when trying to grant a user write access**. Even if this is not possible, any kind if user feedback (message, popup, ...) stating so would be nicer than just an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit read/write access doesn't work for public rooms. That feature is used for gallery rooms.

If a user reached 20 reputation on the main site then it'll take a few minutes to sync that change in reputation to the chat system.

Comment: That could be it, but why the read/write access include in their description: "**Regardless of the room's general access setting**"? I thought that meant public or gallery room.

Comment: Re "a few minutes" - sync is hourly, or at login, or on-request by a moderator

Comment: @VonC: These settings never *remove* any rights; they just *add* them (it says "Regardless of ... they will be able to read", not "they will *only* be able to read"). I'll clarify the wording a bit.

Comment: @balpha: thank you for the clarification :)